# Error in stateflow

Tags: matlab, embedded, simulink, stateflow

I have a problem, when I am running my model.
The error is:

> Error reported by S-function 'sf_sfun' in
>   'duo/Subsystem2/Genset1/Primover and generator/Electrical system/
>   SFunction ': Stateflow Suppress Error.
>
> > failed assertion in .\utils\object.cpp at line 2850:    object[id]!=NULL
> >     Stack Trace:   [  0] 000000018000DCC4                libut.dll+056516
> >     (MathWorks::I18N::Utf8String::clone+000260)   [  1] 0000000180010E6C
> >     libut.dll+069228 (utDumpStackTrace+000492)   [  2] 0000000041A52615
> >     sf.mexw64+2631189 (dd::DDException::~DDException+004277)   [  3]
> >     0000000041B7E7F8                sf.mexw64+3860472
> >     (TagVisitorTraverserSF::`vftable'+478424) MATLAB m-file stack trace:
> >
> > > In stateflow\private\get_sf_block_port_info at 8

When I am opening the function `get_sf_block_port_info` I am getting this function

```
    function portInfo = get_sf_block_port_info(sfunId,varargin)

% Copyright 2003-2004 The MathWorks, Inc.

blockId = get_param(sfunId, 'parent');
chartId = block2chart(blockId);
try
    portInfo = sf('Cg','get_chart_port_info',chartId,varargin{:});
catch
    portInfo = [];
end
```

I tried to change varargin{:} to do it varargin, but I cannot make any changes.

Comment: Can you check whether your Simulink version is compatible with your Simulink model? I once had a similar error message and it was because of compatibility problems.

Comment: I encountered the same error a second time and restarting Matlab solved it.